# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.io.matlab'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, python-import, importerror

I've seen so many questions about this error online, but even after reading through all of them, I have no idea why I am still getting this error. I have spicy installed, and I am completely lost as to what to do. All I'm trying to do is get an example working that I found online, but this ModuleError keeps appearing.

Here are the imports below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/Users/.../PycharmProjects/SVM/venv/example1.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from ._olivetti_faces import fetch_olivetti_faces
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/_olivetti_faces.py", line 20, in <module>
    from scipy.io.matlab import loadmat
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/io/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from .matlab import loadmat, savemat, whosmat, byteordercodes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.io.matlab'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated so much!! I am using Mac OS, and I have 3.7 python installed through Anaconda.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade sklearn`

Comment: If you are within `conda`, using `pip` can lead to an unstable environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a fresh environment and install your packages with conda.

```
conda create -n testenv python=3.7 matplotlib numpy scikit-learn scipy
```

Then run your code within this environment.

Comment: How/Where do I create a new environment? Would I use this line on terminal?

Comment: Yes, you would do this in a terminal.